# HTML email signature rejected by recipients

Tags: html, css, email

I've coded an email signature for my company. It looks as I want, it uses inline CSS and appropriate HTML so that it's compatible with all major email clients. Always looks correct when emails are received.

However, we're finding many companies we email reject the email because of the email signature. I have no images in the code, so why would the code below cause these rejections?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<br /><br />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="70" style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px; border-top:1px solid #cccccc;"><br /></td>
    <td width="230"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:18px; line-height:24px; color:#333333;">
      <b>Joe Blogs</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:#999999;">
      Deputy Editor - My Company<br /><br />
      <a href="http://xxxxxx.co.uk/" title="xxxxx" style="color:#6bb4c2; text-decoration:none;">xxxxxx.co.uk</a><br />
      <a href="https://twitter.com/xxxxxx" title="Twitter" style="color:#6bb4c2; text-decoration:none;">Twitter</a> - <a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx" title="Facebook" style="color:#6bb4c2; text-decoration:none;">Facebook</a> - <a href="https://instagram.com/xxxxxx/" title="Instagram" style="color:#6bb4c2; text-decoration:none;">Instagram</a> - <a href="http://issuu.com/xxxxxx" title="Issuu" style="color:#6bb4c2; text-decoration:none;">Issuu</a><br />
      7 Somewhere Lane, London, SW7 8HG<br />
      Office: 020 2346735 | Direct: 07887 222777
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Nothing really looks like it could cause any issues in the code that you have included. Maybe you have a suspicious looking company name or the domain which handles your email has been blacklisted for spam because of another company sharing your external IP address. You could try to use an online tool which will let you test an actual email and get a spam score in return... https://www.mail-tester.com/